# Recovery volume appears in Time Machine backup ; how to exclude?

Tags: backup, time-machine, recovery

The rare times I open my Time Machine backup folder, I see "Recovery" appearing for each backup.

For example:
[image: Recovery Volume appears in each Time Machine backup]
Since I don't really need Recovery in Time Machine (as far as I know, each bootable drive has its own Recovery volume which you would boot from in case of emergency) and that Recovery volume represents at least a gig per backup, I'm wondering if there is a way to *exclude* the Recovery volume from being backed up.

Or am I wrong about my assumption that the Recovery volume in a Time Machine backup not necessary for restoring a completely borked drive?

Comment: If the recovery folder stays the same, it is 1GB for *all backups together*. Time Machine backups by only copying changed media. Therefore your first backup takes quite sime time, but the incremental ones afterward will be much faster, depending on how much data has changed.

Comment: TM shouldn't backup anything that's not mounted - is one of your Recoveries mounted?

Comment: No, recovery is never explicitly mounted, but it always appears in the list of volumes backed up.

Answer (score -1):

First, open system preferences.

[image]
Next, open the time machine pane of system preferences. Wait for any ongoing backups to complete, then click the options button in the bottom right hand corner:
[image]

From here, click the plus icon in the bottom right corner, select the folder you want to EXCLUDE from backups (in this case recovery), and hit save. You can also select an external drive (most likely already in there) and hit minus to have that drive backed up as well.

[image]

Comment: You can't select anything that's not mounted, & Recovery should never be mounted.

Comment: Recovery is never mounted, so I'm not sure why it's always appearing under every backup.  Regardless, the unmounted volume can't be explicitly excluded via Time Machine preferences.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Oh - that reminds me of something. Once I let TM backup my flash drive, thinking I'd want to keep a backup of it. I never used my flash drive since then, but the flash drive kept showing up in every backup. So I erased the disk & re-added it as a disk, and the flash drive stopped showing up. Maybe try this?